# VS Code Auto formatação colchetes na linha de baixo

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Olá! Ativei a auto formatação, como padrão ele salva os colchetes de uma classe ou função na linha de baixo.

Mas queria que ele salvasse também de todas as condições, acho que fica mais bonito e organizado.

Atualmente:

```
if ($this->UsersDB->isPermission("servers_del") && !empty($serversInfos)) {
   $this->ServersDB->del("id", $id);
}
```

Desejado:

```
if ($this->UsersDB->isPermission("servers_del") && !empty($serversInfos))
{
    $this->ServersDB->del("id", $id);
}
```

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?

Comment: isso é algum plugin de formatação ou do eslint que vc instalou que está configurado para aplicar a formação ao salvar, tem que remover essa config no plugin

Comment: é configuração padrão de auto salvar formatando os códigos, mas gostaria de customizar essa parte.

Comment: @novic, as configs do VsCode nem sempre seguem o mesmo esquema do VisualStudio. Isso https://stackoverflow.com/a/48729755/1518921 provavelmente resolve sua duvida. Se alguém desejar formular uma resposta fique a vontade, recomendo testar primeiro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu vi errado, eu sei que são totalmente diferentes vou remover a sinalização, eu achei que fosse visual studio a ferramenta completa! falha minha!

Comment: Ok muito obrigado!!! Ajudou muito o link postado.

Answer (score -1):

Se você usa Intelephense, vá em Extension Settings, procure por Format: Braces e troque de psr12 para allman. Vai resolver.